# Solder various parts of broken wire in a fan coil

Tags: motor, ac, soldering, coil, fan

So, in a not that careful attempt to open holes on a fan to get the air to go through it more (it heated up a bit too much compared to another fan in the house), I broke the coil wire in some points...

Is it possible to solder it back without insulating? Or this would reduce the impedance and then have some bad consequence on the fan? Or forgetting the impedance, maybe the electrons would just stop going through parts of the coil ("easier" if there's a smaller path) and the fan wouldn't work decently, maybe even slower (because of the shorter path of electrons) or something?

If I do have to insulate the wire after soldering, could it be with electrical tape? Or it needs some thing more advanced? (I've been learning more deeply about soldering because I only knew soldering iron + tin = stuff soldered 2 weeks ago, so I don't have advanced things, but I can try to buy the needed thing if the ones I have are not enough.)

Actually... Can it be done at all? Bellow goes a picture of the broken wire in some points. I haven't turned on the fan since I broke them, so no idea if I should and see what happens? Because it's the same wire, just touching on itself in some points, so I guess it shouldn't short-circuit it?

[image]

PS: I know I could just buy another one, but why not learn a bit more and try to fix this one haha (again, if it can actually be done, as broken on one point only it would be easier with the insulation since all the rest is insulated, but broken on various points ones bellow the others I guess it may be harder).

Thanks in advance for any help! Also hopefully this is a good place to ask this kind of question... I'm sorry if it's not.

Comment: Honestly, I see two options. 1) Remove the coil from the stator and rewind it with new wire. 2} Replace the fan (motor) with a working (or new) one.

Comment: I actually had a stator like this, I ended up touching the broken ends together and it worked. Maybe you could do the same thing with solder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be enough slack to get the proper broken ends to overlap each other and twist them together to get enough of a mechanical connection for the solder to hold them together. You would need to have some additional wire of the same size to overlap the gaps. You would need to remove the insulating varnish from the areas that need to be soldered.

As mentioned in another answer, you need to connect the wires as they were originally. Each broken end must be reconnected to the end it has broken from. If you get them mixed up, part of the coils will be bypassed. I would not be confident that you can determine what goes where with a multimeter.

Getting the wires re-insulated will be challenging. The wire must not "touch on itself." That would bypass some turns of the coil. Depending on where that happens, the fan could get hot and burn immediately or sometime later.

This might be a good challenge to learn from, but it you are successful, I would still not consider it safe the leave the fan running when you are not watching it. Give it a try, but buy a new fan and throw the old one away regardless of the outcome.

Comment: What if I just put the wires close enough and connect them with solder and that's it? (no twisting) Since I just broke them, they should at minimum get to touch eachother in a point (or anyways, be close enough for me to solder them). About removing the insulating varnish I'm not sure because I haven't read much about it yet, but with headphones, I've let the soldering iron melt the insulation with a bit of solder in the tip and after a bit, solder sticks to the wire (insulation gone) - not sure if this can be done here too? Maybe if I increase the temperature of the iron?

Comment: You will need two very steady hands to hold the ends together, a third to hold the solder and a fourth to hold the soldering iron. If you do it carefully, you will have a joint that will not be particularly strong, but might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can solder the connections and ensure that they won't come into contact with anything conductive like they case, or eachother it should be ok. If you have insulating varnish to put over the connection that's ideal.

You will also have to make sure the wires are connected as they were originally so you don't accidentally bypass part of the coil. A multimeter will be helpful for this.

Comment: How could I know which end of a wire is the correct one for the wire end I chose with a multimeter? (I'm sorry, I didn't get how I'd do it - ohmmeter somehow?) Also, why only put insulating varnish over the connection and not bellow it too? (By not putting bellow, won't the connection not be insulated bellow the solder part?)

Comment: By the way, if after soldering I'd put a bit of electrical tape over the connection, then solder another connection and put a bit more over that (would get tape over tape over tape...) - would this give the same result as the varnish? Or what's the advantage of it over the electrical tape? (Only not getting as awful as it would the way I said? Maybe I'd obstruct heat from going that well where the tape is on? Or it insulates more or something? Maybe if I'd put more layers of electrical tape it would put them equal in insulating?) Asking for me to understand one vs the other.

Comment: Tape should be ok if it fits. Electrical tape will degrade over time however. A coil with 2 breaks is essentially 3 coils. One tap (I'll call it the input tap) will be electrically connect to a corresponding wire at the break, That's coil 1. 2 of the wires at the break will be electrically connected. That's coil 2. The output tap will be connected to the remaining wire at the break, that's coil 3. Connect the coils in series to repair the original coil.

Comment: Oh I didn't know electrical tape would degrade over time. Interesting. Thank you. Also, what about the multimeter? How could I use it to know which wire connects to which wire?